# AMD Radeon 520 dedicated graphics card not working properly in Xwayland

Tags: laptop, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics

The tl;dr about this question is - Is my radeon 520 dedicated card working fine? Do I need to set  "xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink radeon Intel" in Wayland to configure hybrid graphics? Xrandr is not working well in weston/wayland.

Long version:

I installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my newly bought HP Laptop (Model: HP 15-BS576TX) which has a dedicated AMD 520 2GB DDR3 graphics card and Intel HD 620 onboard graphics in a Kabylake Core i5 processor system. This is the first time I'm installing Linux on a hybrid graphics card setup on a laptop.

Now, Ubuntu 17.10 defaults with Xwayland instead of Xorg/XFree86. I find it confusing to configure AMD Radeon 520 dedicated graphics. The confusing part is xrander --listproviders only list the intel hd 620 integrated graphics.

`xrandr --listproviders`
 `Providers: number : 0`

But, lspci -knnn shows that AMD Radeon 520 card is detected:

`01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / R7 M520] [1002:6660] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430] [103c:832b]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu`

and Integrated Intel HD 620 graphics:

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 [8086:5916] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company HD Graphics 620 [103c:832b]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915`

`lshw -C video
  *-display

       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:b0000000-b0ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / R7 M520]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:129 memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:b1200000-b123ffff ioport:5000(size=256) memory:b1240000-b125ffff`

I'm booting with `radeon.modeset=1` which is added to the grub bootloader entry.

Now, if I run any app with `DRI_PRIME=1` it works and shows below info:

`:~$ DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo |grep -i Opengl*
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: AMD HAINAN (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.13.0-16-generic, LLVM 5.0.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.2.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50`

So, I assumed Radeon 520 is working fine. **Then, noticed that there is no mention of gallium 3d**? But, why Xrandr is not showing dedicated card as one of the providers?

I see that there is amdgpu driver module also loaded. From the list, R520 card seems to be supported by the radeon driver.

`lsmod |grep radeon
radeon               1470464  0
ttm                    94208  2 amdgpu,radeon
i2c_algo_bit           16384  3 amdgpu,radeon,i915
drm_kms_helper        167936  3 amdgpu,radeon,i915
drm                   356352  28 amdgpu,radeon,i915,ttm,drm_kms_helper`

Wnat needs to be done now? I have no custom scripts or files placed in /etc/X11 directory.

Do I need to remove any xserver drivers? like xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu?

Comment: I can't tell what your question is. Many x apps do not work in wayland , xrandr is one that does not work. You can run an x session but what makes you think you need to start removing stuff?

Comment: @Panther the problem is, in wayland session the hybrid graphics is not detected and configured. If I run DRI_PRIME=1 xyz it will run as verified by radeontop tool. However, as shown in the below screenshot, Ubuntu or wayland does not auto-configure it. Gnome settings info should ideally list both the integrated and dedicated card in information. But, it is not so. Neither is any mention about Gallium 3D working with this radeon card. http://image.ibb.co/hHv3qm/amd_intel_hybrid_gfx.png

Comment: In the tl;Dr you answered your own question. Wala d does not support xrandr. You may consider filing a bug report against wayland

Comment: As of now, I filed a new bug report in Ubuntu BTS about wayland. But, it seems like there are a lot of components that are affected like gnome-control-centre which is not showing dedicated card and nicely autoconfigure it, XrandR which is now just an Xorg tool no more working good in Wayland session.